# Speeding up text cleaning with lots of stopwords

Tags: python, nltk

I have a database of text data and created a small counter to get the word counts from the entire database. The most common words are the usual suspects ('is', 'and', etc.) and the least common are an assorted of emojis, dollar values, typos and so on. I'd like to remove the words from the text so that I can vectorize just the values that are not the most or least common. But the list of highly uncommon/aberrant words is roughly 600,000 items long:

```
   stopwords = []

    for key, value in ctr.items(): #ctr is a Counter() object of words in the entire corpus of text and their counts
        if value < 4:
            words += 1
            stopwords.append(key)

print (len(stopwords))
643392
```

That means, taking an example of tokenizing just one piece of text:

```
    start = time.time()

[word for word in word_tokenize(stemmer.stem(dataframe.text[20])) if word not in stopwords]

end = time.time()

print (end - start)

79.92309927940369
```

So, over a minute for a single piece of text. There are roughly 160,000 articles to clean and vectorize.

Is there some kind of vectorized function for stopword removal? The only ways I've seen of dealing with stopwords address the problem iteratively. At this rate, cleaning this text will take about three months.

Thanks as always for any help.

Comment: That's definitely a case where multi threading could improve the execution time. Another thing would be to have a MCVE to be able to see better where your bottleneck might be: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is there a way to provide a MCVE when the list of stopwords is so large? Is this a scenario where I should just create a dropbox link or something?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it helps but maybe this might speed things up a little: https://github.com/alvations/earthy/blob/master/FAQ.md#what-else-can-earthy-do

Answer (score 2):

Word lookup shouldn't take that long in Python. You don't need to vectorize stopword removal, you just need to fix your code. You don't show your code but chances are that `stopwords` is an enormous list. Convert it to a set and your problems should go away.

```
stopwords = set(stopwords)
```

Second, again you don't show full code but I really doubt you have a stemmer that can stem a multi-word string. Tokenize the string first, then stem each word.

Comment: apologies, i couldn't get this until now. the list is already a set since it came from a Counter(), so each one of those words is unique. that's the challenge

Comment: It's not about uniqueness, it's about access time. But maybe your stemmer is choking on the document-length string you give it, who knows. You're doing something wrong, but you are not showing the crucial code so nobody can help you.

Comment: Also if you took `Counter.keys()`, it's a list. Where is your code?

Comment: I genuinely don't know what code to add to make this clarify this. Changing the list to a set did nothing to reduce the time.

Comment: It WILL reduce the time. What you need to add is a minimal script that can be run on its own. Yours isn't even indented sensibly. Include the code that loads the dataframe and the stopwords database, the conversion to a set, and the loop that uses them to stem.